# check_box always submitting as 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

The data goes into the database, but it's always submitting the :location as 0. How do I avoid this? I want the :location to submit the checked value.

Also, would it be easier to use simple_form instead of doing it like this?

**Here's the partial:**

```
<%= form_for(@offering) do |f| %>

    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @offering %>

    <%= f.label :description, "Description:" %> 

    <%= f.text_field :description %>


  <%= f.label :location, "Where?" %>

  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Alphabet City") %>Alphabet City
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Battery Park") %>Battery Park
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Chelsea") %>Chelsea
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Chinatown") %>Chinatown

  <%= f.submit "Post your offering" %> 
  <% end %>
```

**Here's the html it produces:**

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/offerings" class="new_offering" id="new_offering" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="L6oao6csQJ9TIRpEKG4BAzj3uH6FUMr9YmDYXx2HbFg="></div>



      <label for="offering_description">Description:</label> 

      <input id="offering_description" name="offering[description]" size="30" type="text">


      <label for="offering_location">Where?</label>

      <input name="offering[location]" type="hidden" value="0">

      <input id="offering_location" name="offering[location]" type="checkbox" value="Alphabet City">Alphabet City

      <input name="offering[location]" type="hidden" value="0">

      <input id="offering_location" name="offering[location]" type="checkbox" value="Battery Park">Battery Park

      <input name="offering[location]" type="hidden" value="0">

      <input id="offering_location" name="offering[location]" type="checkbox" value="Chelsea">Chelsea

      <input name="offering[location]" type="hidden" value="0">

      <input id="offering_location" name="offering[location]" type="checkbox" value="Chinatown">Chinatown


      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Post your offering"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

the hidden inputs some how over ride the checkboxes.

So instead of check_box, i'm using check_box_tag like this:

```
  <%= check_box_tag("offering[location]", "Alphabet City") %>Alphabet City
  <%= check_box_tag("offering[location]", "Battery Park") %>Battery Park
  <%= check_box_tag("offering[location]", "Chelsea") %>Chelsea
  <%= check_box_tag("offering[location]", "Chinatown") %>Chinatown
```

instead of:

```
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Alphabet City") %>Alphabet City
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Battery Park") %>Battery Park
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Chelsea") %>Chelsea
  <%= check_box("offering", :location, {}, "Chinatown") %>Chinatown
```